# Tar file for a date getting corrupt

Tags: python

I am trying to archive old files from a file server using python 2.6. I am creating tar files based on date. Below is my code :

```
#/usr/bin/python

import os, time, tarfile
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import datetime

path = "/nfs4exports/opt/prod/fmac/files/inbound/test_archive"
count = 0
set_date = '2010-12-17'

base_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(set_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

# Creating dictionary for files to be archived
date_file_dict = {}
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            file = os.path.join(root,file)
            file = os.path.join(path, file)
            stats = os.stat(file)
            c_date = date.fromtimestamp(stats[8]).strftime('%m-%d-%y')
            date_file_tuple = c_date, file
            date_file_dict[file] = c_date

d_list = date_file_dict.values()
dd_list = list(set(d_list))
date_occur_dict = {}

# Adding files to archive and generating log
for search_date in dd_list:
    tar_file = "nas_archive_" + search_date + ".tgz"
    mytar = tarfile.open(tar_file,"w:gz")
    log_file = "archive_log_" + search_date
    fcount = 0
    #print tar_file
    #print log_file
    f = open(log_file,'ab+')
    for f_name, d_date in date_file_dict.iteritems():
        if d_date == search_date:
            fcount += 1
            mytar.add(f_name)
            f.write(f_name + '\n')
    date_occur_dict[search_date] = fcount

# Checking before removing files
for check_count in dd_list:
    if d_list.count(check_count) == date_occur_dict.get(check_count):
        for f_name, d_date in date_file_dict.iteritems():
            if d_date == check_count:
                os.remove(f_name)
```

Above code works perfectly fine and generates archive files and log correctly except for date 11-15-12. Archive file "nas_archive_11-15-12.tgz" is getting generated every time when i run the script but somehow gets corrupted.

```
tar -tzvf nas_archive_11-15-12.tgz
-rw-r--r-- appins/app     1961 2012-11-15 15:09:56 nfs4exports/opt/prod/fmac/files/inbound/test_archive/Input_379a6265-a121-4040-8014-babe397e98ed.txt.gpg
-rw-r--r-- appins/app     2337 2012-11-15 10:25:09 nfs4exports/opt/prod/fmac/files/inbound/test_archive/Input_839c5bc5-a6b8-4fef-bb26-e1d8e91b3f84.txt.gpg

gzip: -rw-r--r-- appins/app     5102 2012-11-15 15:04:33 nfs4exports/opt/prod/fmac/files/inbound/test_archive/Input_5c8b315b-7b99-42d3-9cc7-235b72ab9176.txt.gpg
stdin: unexpected end of file
-rw-r--r-- appins/app     1445 2012-11-15 10:19:06 nfs4exports/opt/prod/fmac/files/inbound/test_archive/Output_ad548dea-374c-47c8-a6f4-a6780af0ab43.csv.gpg
-rw-r--r-- appins/app     1344 2012-11-15 15:13:48 nfs4exports/opt/prod/fmac/files/inbound/test_archive/Output_66d20187-1e99-438d-9860-73d0fa6ead04.csv.gpg
-rw-r--r-- appins/app     2635 2012-11-15 16:09:51 nfs4exports/opt/prod/fmac/files/inbound/test_archive/Output_894a2cd2-1e39-46a9-b805-201b5d430181.csv.gpg
-rw-r--r-- appins/app     3997 2012-11-15 15:02:32 nfs4exports/opt/prod/fmac/files/inbound/test_archive/Input_6104d8b7-47fd-4d49-aa7e-1e0fc404fbcb.txt.gpg
-rw-r--r-- appins/app     2603 2012-11-15 09:46:29 nfs4exports/opt/prod/fmac/files/inbound/test_archive/Input_e23cf5f5-11de-45c5-a2d3-2403a28068fe.txt.gpg
-rw-r--r-- appins/app     2325 2012-11-15 14:37:06 nfs4exports/opt/prod/fmac/files/inbound/test_archive/Input_882db028-1a06-422f-9192-fe3fc58e2e3f.txt.gpg
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I checked disk space also and it is not a problem. I tried to create files manually for "Nov 15 2012" using touch but for that also archive file is getting corrupted. Other archive files are perfectly fine and i can restore them without any problem. Can anyone point out the problem here?

Comment: Maybe try adding an explicit close on `mytar`.  It might not be terminating the archive correctly.

Comment: Bulls eye!!!!. It worked.

Comment: @user2501825 Note that Python 2.6 (and later) has the `with` statement, which can help you with this. If you get into the habit of using it consistently, you'll never forget a `close`. http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/whatsnew/pep-343.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicating my comment as an answer:

*Maybe try adding an explicit close on mytar. It might not be terminating the archive correctly.*